# Como fazer uma barra de progresso do tempo de load da página?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

Como fazer uma barra de progresso que carrega na medida em que a página é carregada?

[image: Barra de progresso]

Como nesse site aqui:

http://sinalverdecaxias.com/

Vi um exemplo no **[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/sergejmueller/pen/kuKtG)**, é meio parecido com isso, não sei como realmente se chama essa barra de progresso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o [pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/), que é bem simples e tem várias opções com visuais bacanas.

Pra por na prática é só fazer o download e adicionar a chamada:

```
<head>
  <script src="/pace/pace.js"></script>
  <link href="/pace/themes/pace-theme-barber-shop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

E depois, fazer as configurações iniciais para personalizar (*não são obrigatórias*) o pace.js:

```
paceOptions = {
  elements: false,
  restartOnRequestAfter: false
}
```

Caso fique com qualquer dúvida tem mais detalhes na [documentação do pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/).